# Class 'MyFirebaseMessagingService' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun zzd(p0: Intent!)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here I have used FirebaseMessagingService in Kotlin but when I run the project it will give me the following error:

> Class 'MyFirebaseMessagingService' is not abstract and does not implement abstract base class member public abstract fun zzd(p0: Intent!): Unit defined in com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService

Any help?

Comment: check this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you aren't using any other play services then upgrade your firebase version to `15.0.2`.

if you are, downgrading to `12.0.1` will work.

Make sure to stick to play service `3.2.1` since `3.3.0` will still crash firebase-config.

Answer (score 18):

Update all your Firebase dependencies to use the latest version: **15.0.2**
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: Thanks @Sergey Ignatyev 
it's working but is you are using play services than you need to downgrade as version 15.0.2 is not available for playservices

Answer (score 4):

On 2nd of May there is a new release that allow the below

> Firebase Android SDKs now have independent version numbers, allowing
>   for more frequent, flexible updates.

So I think now we need to used different versions according to each module, check release notes pages to latest released details 
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem with version 15.0.0.
Downgrade to 12.0.1 solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just update `google-services` to `3.2.1` with `3.3.0` might be some problems

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

and `firebase-messaging` to `15.0.2`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
```

Comment: This does not work if you use firebase-config. Firebase config crashes even if FirebaseApp has been initialised. The best for now is to downgrade until 15 is stable

Answer (score 0):

[**`Firebase Android Release Notes`**](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

```
Firebase Core     com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2
Analytics         com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2
Authentication    com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0
Cloud Firestore   com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0
Cloud Messaging   com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2
```

> Unit defined in
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService

You should **`Downgrade`** version. Use **`15.0.0`**.

```
 com.google.firebase:firebase-****:15.0.0
```

**NOTE**

If the problem still coming, You can use **`stable`** **`12.0.1`**.

```
 com.google.firebase:firebase-****:12.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by -

- Updating

> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:**3.1.0**'  to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:**3.2.1**'
>
> Firebase version from **15.0.0** to **15.0.2** for all except firebase auth as it is at **15.1.0**
>
> At last I updated google play services version from **15.0.0** to **15.0.1**

After all these changes sync your gradle files.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same answer as everyone. You need to update all the firebase and google play services stuff. The thing to take away is that **FIREBASE AND GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES VERSION ARE NOT ALWAYS IN SYNC ANYMORE APPARENTLY**. So if you are using something like

```
ext {
    firebase_version = "15.0.2"
}
```

Just ditch them. For all the versions and stuff,

- Click here for [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)
- Click here for [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)
- Click here for [Google Service Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)