# updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.2

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I have updated my Firebase SDK version. But theres error of updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.2. I tried to make firebase and google services of same version but it wont work.

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.3'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
// if you use the support libraries
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
implementation 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.2'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:1.0.16'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation project(':linkedin-sdk')
implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'
implementation project(':libphonenumber-5.9')
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'
implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Try having the same version (15.0.2) for `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location` as well as `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads`

Comment: It didn't work theres no repository for 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location' and 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads' with version '15.0.2'

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try Below Code:

**1.build.gradle(gradle)**

change :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

To :

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
```

follow below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50152496/6920195

Comment: i was using 3.1.0 when the problem occurred, i just upgraded all firebase packages to latest versions. Changing google-services to 3.2.0 solved my problem.
in addition i have added the following line to repositories
 maven{
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
        }

Answer (score 4):

For anyone checking this, the main reason you get this conflict issue is because you are using an older version of Android Studio.

You need to do the following:

Upgrade Android Studio to version 3.1

add:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

to the (Top-level) build.gradle file, then you will be able to use the newest versions.

Check the below for more information:

[Announcing the new SDK Versioning](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html)

[Compilation failed to complete:Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android)

Answer (score 3):

> A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and Google
>   Play services 15.0.0 or higher

If you want to use **`15.0.2`** then

- Use Latest **`gms`** version.
- Upgrade Android Studio Version.

**DEMO**

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0' 
    }
```

Read [**`Firebase Android Release Notes`**](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

**FYI**

Latest SDK versions

```
Firebase Core     com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2
Ads               com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.0
Analytics         com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2
App Indexing      com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.0
Authentication    com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0
Cloud Firestore   com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0
Cloud Functions   com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:15.0.0
Cloud Messaging   com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2
```

After change **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

**NOTE**

If the same problem coming then **`DOWNGRADLE`** your version.
Use **`12.0.1`**.

Comment: using version 15.0.0 gives error

 Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn

Comment: @AshutoshShrestha Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149536/3395198

Comment: I am using above SDK version but it gives me the following error

'Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.2.
'

Comment: @AshutoshShrestha https://stackoverflow.com/a/50152261/3395198

Comment: downgrading version to 12.0.1 worked.. Thanks

Comment: @AshutoshShrestha I have rectified answer. Kindly review.

Answer (score 0):

Verify you have versions complying to the versions [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)