# Getting Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn error

Tags: android, build.gradle, build-error

I was able to build my gradle without any problem but now suddenly I'm facing this problem.

I've tried to follow similar questions but those were not helpful even I tried to check the `firebase version` but it's updated. Actually I can't exactly figure out where the error is resided.

After trying to check the `gradle` option of sidebar I'm getting following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list. * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at help.gradle.org
```

Error:

```
Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "community.infinity"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
 }

compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
})
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.adamstyrc.cookiecutter:cookie-cutter:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.allattentionhere:fabulousfilter:0.0.5'
implementation 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe:0.1.0'
implementation 'com.thesurix.gesturerecycler:gesture-recycler:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.iammert:MaterialIntroView:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.github.oxoooo:touch-image-view:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.1'
implementation 'com.fenchtose.nocropper:nocropper:0.2.0'
implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
implementation('com.google.guava:guava:23.4-android') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    exclude module: 'support-v13'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
implementation 'com.orhanobut:hawk:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.zsoltsafrany:needle:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.madrapps:pikolo:1.1.6'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.4.0") {
    // Excludes the support library because it's already included by Glide.
    transitive = false
}
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar"
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.1.2'

}


 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation failed to complete:Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting `implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'` this line and try again. It should work.

**EDIT:**

Try upgrading google-services plugin version to `3.3.0` as said in [android-developers blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html). And verify your versions against [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: No it was not helpful