# Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior

Tags: android, android-glide

I got the error when I run the app in **Android Issues : Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior**

here is my **gradle dependencies**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation failed to complete:Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update firebase-auth to 15.1.0 and firebase-storage to 15.0.2.
Now they have independent version numbers.

Also update google-services from project .gradle to:

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'`

Check the release notes [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: My settings where already at this and I am receiving the error still.