# Error using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, adapter

I was trying to modify my old FirebaseAdapter code into new Adapter but i couldnt figure out how the new FirebaseAdapter is used using FirebaseOptions and Query. So i tried the same old way and modified the code but it is now showing this error

```
Program type already present: 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: 
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior, sources=[Unknown 
source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

my new code for the adapter is

```
public class OpeningPage extends Fragment {


public OpeningPage() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}



private RecyclerView mUsersList;

private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private View mMainView;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
 //   View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_opening_page, 
    container, false);
    mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);
    mUsersDatabase = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

    mUsersList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.users_list);

    mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUsersList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    return mMainView;
  }


   @Override
   public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Users")
            .limitToLast(50);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                    .setQuery(query, Users.class)
                    .build();


    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, 
    UsersViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder holder, int 
   position, Users model) {

            holder.setDisplayName(model.getName());
            holder.setUserStatus(model.getStatus());
            holder.setUserImage(model.getThumb_image(), getContext());

            final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), 
    ProfileActivity.class);
                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                    startActivity(profileIntent);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
    viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, parent, false);

            return new UsersViewHolder(view);
        }

    };

    mUsersList.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
   public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDisplayName(String name){

        TextView userNameView = (TextView) 
 mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
        userNameView.setText(name);

    }

    public void setUserStatus(String status){

        TextView userStatusView = (TextView) 
  mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
        userStatusView.setText(status);


    }

    public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){

        CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) 
 mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);

 Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar)
.into(  userImageView);

    }


 }




}
```

Earlier i was using PopulateViewHolder but after upgrading my gradle to
      implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0' 
its no longer working.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont get it can you please post the link here in the comments if the question is a duplicate. so that i can go through the post. is it related to libraries that i have implemented ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android