# Error deploying app with Google Services v15

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I use a couple of Google Services in my Android app and have been on `v11.8.0` until I upgraded to `v15.0.0`. This is the error I get when I try to run the project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer$DefaultMethodFinder.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:483)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:621)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.defaultMethodsDefined(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:331)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visitEnd(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:91)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(ClassVisitor.java:339)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visitEnd(InterfaceDesugaring.java:112)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:702)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbfm
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.findTargetMethod(LambdaDesugaring.java:327)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.queueUpBridgeMethodIfNeeded(LambdaDesugaring.java:236)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring.access$200(LambdaDesugaring.java:56)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:413)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1623)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzbfm
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:66)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseSig(BytecodeDescriptor.java:83)
    at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:54)
    at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:41)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodType.fromMethodDescriptorString(MethodType.java:1067)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.toMethodHandle(LambdaDesugaring.java:660)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.toJvmMetatype(LambdaDesugaring.java:647)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:408)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1623)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbfm not found
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:53)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        versionCode 149
        versionName "1.1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

//        multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-fresco.pro'

            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
            }
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        keepRuntimeAnnotatedClasses false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-rtmp:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:r2.5.4'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.1'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-pinpoint:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.5'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch:3.1.0'
    kapt 'com.airbnb:deeplinkdispatch-processor:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:fresco-processors:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.franmontiel:LocaleChanger:0.9.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    implementation "com.radioafricagroup.payments:payments-sdk:0.0.15"
    implementation "com.radioafricagroup.billing:billing-sdk:0.0.6"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7:$anko_version"
    implementation 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:1.0.16'
    implementation('com.appsee:appsee-android:2.3.4@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.github.ronaldsmartin:Material-ViewPagerIndicator:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:rxgps:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.fondesa:kpermissions:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.hendraanggrian:recyclerview-paginated:0.6'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0-rc1'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:2.1.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I've tried using `v15.0.2` of `Firebase` services and `v15.0.1` of `Google` services but they all yield the same result.

Reverting everything back to `v11.8.0` works but any update won't. What's changed?

I've updated by `Google services plugin` version to `3.3.0` but the issue still persists.

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.4'
    ext.google_services_version = '15.0.2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
}
```

I've cleaned the project multiple times, invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio multiple times as well but nothing's changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation failed to complete:Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android)

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have but nothing's changed. I am using v3.3.0 of google-services and the latest firebase and google-services versions but the error is still there.

Comment: clean and rebuild the project, also which android studio are u using? @AlexKombo

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 3.1.2. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times to no avail. I've just reverted back to `11.8.0` and moved on until I find a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [`https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) and adding appropriate firebase Services in your Android Project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the google play services plugin 3.3.0:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

Comment: I've made this change but the error still persists.

Comment: Updated your dependencies to the latest available with version 15: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: I am using `v15.0.2` for `Firebase core, auth and config` and `v15.0.1` for `play-services-gcm` and `play-services-auth`