# Cannot resolve google play services version 15.0.2

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I want to install Google play services 15.0.2 (because 15.0.0 create a dexing error I don't know why) I have these errors from gradle :

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.2
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.2
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.2
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

But I've never put these dependencies in any build.gradle.
If I want to install with the install button, I have the error :
Could not find dependency

This is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

def DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION             = 25
def DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION             = "25.0.2"
def DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION              = 25
def DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION    = "15.0.2"

android {
compileSdkVersion project.hasProperty('compileSdkVersion') ? 
project.compileSdkVersion : DEFAULT_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
buildToolsVersion project.hasProperty('buildToolsVersion') ? 
project.buildToolsVersion : DEFAULT_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 
project.hasProperty('buildToolsVetargetSdkVersionrsion') ? 
project.buildToolsVersion : DEFAULT_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    def googlePlayServicesVersion = 
project.hasProperty('googlePlayServicesVersion') ? 
project.googlePlayServicesVersion : DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    compile 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar'
}
```

EDIT :
I succeeded to solve my problem.
Actually, I had a multidex script in my parent build.gradle which force updated all my com.gms.google to 15.0.2 but as you said, google play services don't have 15.0.2.
I just removed this script and it worked

Comment: instead of importing all google services , that causes dex error because of the quantity of methods, i would suggest just implementing the ones you will use in your app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation failed to complete:Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android)

Comment: See this blog post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

Comment: did you manage tofind a solution @Psyycker?

Comment: I finally could resolve my problem, see edit to see how I did. ADM answer was usefull to understand why I could not download google play services 15.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase libraries now have independent versions, as opposed to the same version they shared before. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).
So this is working for now, but it might be different in the future:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
```

And more importantly, firebase libs no longer have the same version as the google play services ones, there is no version 15.0.2 for play services libraries such as location, see [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), the latest is 15.0.0.

My advice is to define each library individually.

To fix you problem change this :

```
def DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION    = "15.0.0"
```

and this:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
```